How many hyper-spherical segments could be placed on N-hypersphere?
Optimistic assessment would be $A_n/A$ in terms of this wiki article I believe that if we take into account form of the hyper-spherical cap real number of caps in hyper-sphere is much lower than this OA. I think that any reasonable pessimistic assessments are considered as a valid answers for this.
The dual (and also practical) problem might sound like this: What is the maximum inverse cosine distance between vectors in one group is possible if it is necessary to place M groups in one N-hyper-sphere?

Lets use hyper-spherical segments.
Hypersphere can described as a sum of hyper-spherical segments with angle bounds.
For $N$-dimensional hyper-sphere there will be $N-1$ coordinates (angles $\alpha_1...\alpha_{N-1}$) which describes all points on its $N-1$ surface.
It is valid to assume that any hyper-spherical cap be placed inside such segment. If for each spherical cap angle $a_{cap}$ is a maximum angle for any two vectors inside it. Then hyper-spherical segment with size $a_{cap}$ on each angle dimension may contain this cap.
Knowing that $\alpha_2...\alpha_{N-1} \in [-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\alpha_1 \in [0,\pi)$ we can say hyper-sphere may contain $M$ hyper-caps where $M=\lfloor \frac{2\pi}{\alpha_{cap}} \rfloor \lfloor \frac{\pi}{\alpha_{cap}} \rfloor ^{N-2}$
